# Sending dynamically created html content through email with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, dynamic

I'm making a simple todo list: http://jsbin.com/pemeqeni/1/edit?html,output

I want to be able to email myself the list, and I'm wondering how to do this with PHP specifically. I thought about scraping the HTML with DOMdocument, but I think that will only get the content from the static HTML page, which will never have list items. My other idea is to dynamically create a bunch of hidden input fields in the emailForm and dynamically delete them just as I do with the list items. Are there any other options? What's the standard protocol for something like this?

Comment: Just take the innerHTML of the container of the list and submit it using AJAX, or put it as the value of a hidden field and submit as a  form?

Comment: Second @PhistucK.  Either way you're going to have to add some more javascript.  Are you familiar with how to pass variables to PHP?

Comment: I'm brand new to PHP. The only way I know is by sending the form to a PHP file and then in the PHP file declaring: `$var = $_GET['formElementName'];`

Comment: What I ended up doing was putting the page inside a form element, and attaching hidden input values to each new div created. [link](http://jsbin.com/pemeqeni/4/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for getting all list elements.

```
<script>
function getEachListElement() {
   var testList = document.getElementsByClassName("todoBody");
   for (var i = 0; i < testList.length; i++) {
       document.writeln(testList[i].innerHTML);
   }
}
</script>
```

Try it out by changing your form action to this

```
<form name="emailForm" method="GET" action="JavaScript:getEachListElement()">
```

Then you can just create a string that you pass to PHP to email to yourself.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something, but the for loop is only iterating once for me. I added some alerts to check, and `i` increments to 1, and then it doesn't repeat. It looks fine to me though.

Comment: Whoops. Try `window.alert(testList[i].innerHTML);` instead of `document.writeln(testList[i].innerHTML);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the php mail function?

ie

```
<?
mail( $email, $subject , $text );
?>
```

Instead of get I would use post then set up a php script you call where you put your values(strings) into variables using $_post and use the mail function to mail those variables(strings).

just to be more clear your html would look like this

```
<form name="emailForm" method="POST" action="getContent.php">
                <input type="text" name="email" value="email"><input type="submit" value="send">
            </form>
```

Your getContent.php would then look like this

```
<?

$myemail = "myemail@tada.com";
$email = $_POST["email"];

mail ($myemail, 'The shiz you wanted', $email);

?>
```